# Basic HTML Function Call with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to learn basic HTML and Javascript, and am not sure what is wrong with this code. It is probably a very simple error and I'm sorry if it is. When I try clicking the buttons, Chrome says in the console that "correct" and "incorrect" are not defined, but I have checked the syntax for the functions and I can't see what is wrong. Thanks for your help :)

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Question 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Q1: What is the height of the Eiffel Tower?</p>
<br>

<script>
function incorrect()
{
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = 
    "incorrect!
    <br>
    <a href="q2.htm">Next Question</a>";
}

function correct()
{
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML =
    "Correct!
    <br>
    <a href="q2.htm">Next Question</a>";
}
</script>

<button onclick="incorrect()">767m</buttton>
<br>
<button onclick="incorrect()">442m</button>
<br>
<button onclick="correct()">324m</button>
<br>
<button onclick="incorrect()">278m</button>
<p id="feedback"></p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the console log in Chrome (press F12 to enter Developer Tools where you can see the log), you will see an error message “Unexpected token ILLEGAL”. The reason is that you have line breaks inside a JavaScript string, which is not permitted, so the function definitions fail in parsing. Moreover, you are using quotes inside a quoted string, which isn’t permitted either. Use single quotes (') as inner quotes or (in this case) just omit them, e.g.

```
function incorrect()
{
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = 
    "incorrect!<br><a href=q2.htm>Next Question</a>";
}
```

Comment: In this the only case in which the hyperlink would still function with the quotes removed?

Comment: @user: HTML attribute values  only have to be in quotes If they contain special values, such as spaces or > . There is an abundance of information about HTML, you just have to search for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have confusing ""(double quotes) in the innerHTML strings. Try this:

instead of `"q2.htm"` use `'q2.htm'`

```
<script>
function incorrect()
{
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = 
    "incorrect!<br><a href='q2.htm'>Next Question</a>";
}

function correct()
{
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML =
    "Correct!<br><a href='q2.htm'>Next Question</a>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but it still doesn't solve the problem. Chrome says "Uncaught ReferenceError: incorrect/correct is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<script>
function incorrect()
{
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = 
    "incorrect!<br><a href='q2.htm'>Next Question</a>";
}

function correct()
{
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML =
    "Correct!<br><a href='q2.htm'>Next Question</a>";
}
</script>
```

You have to put them on the same line or use concatenation.